# Footer not showing in iTextSharp v4

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to create a PDF from HTML, and am using iTextSharp for that.  From my reading, the license that covers the newer versions of iTextSharp would require me to make the source code available.  We can't do that, so we're using version 4, which is under the LGPL.

I'm trying to get a footer to appear along with the HTML, but it's not working for some reason.  I've tried removing the HTML and just using text.  Just putting a chunk in the footer.  Multiple pages vs single pages.  Hopefully I'm just missing something easy, but from the examples I've seen it should be super easy.

```
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 35,35,35,70);

        var font = FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8f);
        font.Color = Color.BLACK;
        var chunk = new Chunk("Footer", font);
        var phrase = new Phrase(chunk);
        var footer = new HeaderFooter(phrase, true);
        footer.Alignment = 1;
        footer.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        doc.Footer = footer;

        //doc.Footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Footer"),false);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);
        using (var sr = new StringReader(html))
        {
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Chunk("Text"));
            //htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
            doc.Close();
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You are using `HTMLWorker`, which has long been deprecated, because it is rather limited for html2pdf conversion. You should use `XMLWorker`, which is available for newer versions of iText. That means upgrading iText, either with an AGPL license, which means disclosing your own source *(you already disclosed part of your source here on Stack Overflow)*, or you purchase a commercial license and you don't disclose your source. Since you don't want to do either, your question is *neigh impossible* to answer. Sorry, Kyle.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse You're telling me that even though there is a HeaderFooter class in iText 4, and there are instructions on how to create a Footer in iText 4, that there is no way to create a Footer in iText 4?  I don't believe you.

Comment: Nope, I'm not telling that at all. I'm only stating that iTextSharp 4.1.6 was superseded by iText(Sharp) 5 in 2009, and `HTMLWorker` was superseded by `XMLWorker` in 2011, so you are using obsolete technology.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I'm already aware of that.  I'm pretty sure I said that in the post.  That doesn't make my question unanswerable, just like any questions about supporting IE8 aren't unanswerable.  There are still people who use old technologies, and StackOverflow is a place that hopefully you can find these people.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Watch your HeaderFooter ctor. The signature your are using might lead to setting the header text only.

Anyway maybe use the PdfWriter.PageEvent and some class deriving from PdfPageEventHelper to implement header and footer (instead of HeaderFooter())

Comment: I tried using the other constructor, but there was no difference.  Neither a footer nor a header show up even if I set them both.  PdfPageEventHelper doesn't help because it's only in newer versions of iText

Comment: Whats your version? 4.1.6.0 (last "free" one) supports PageEventHelper stuff.